# Table elements executing a function

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have this table:

```
maps = {4707191, 4747722, 1702169, 3994471, 4708958, 4008546, 4323335, 4516043, 4612295, 3469987, 4337892, 238378, 3088188, 329627, 3526384, 433483}
```

How can I make a script so if `1702169` (for example) is picked from the table, it prints ''That's the number''?

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: I tried:  if maps["1702169"] then
print('Thats the number')
end

Comment: What do you mean by "picked from the table"? Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do what (i think) you want is with pairs() function.  This is a stateless iterator which you can read more about here: http://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html

If you simply want to scan through the entire table and see if it contains a value, then you can use this simple code:

```
local maps = {4707191, 4747722, 1702169, 3994471, 4708958, 4008546, 4323335, 4516043, 4612295, 3469987, 4337892, 238378, 3088188, 329627, 3526384, 433483}

local picked = 1702169

for i, v in pairs(maps) do
  if v == picked then
    print("That's the number")
    break
  end
end
```

The above code will iterate through the whole table where `i` is the `key` and `v` is the `value` of the `table[key]=value` pairs.

I am slightly unclear about your end goal, but you could create this into a function and/or modify it to your actual needs.  Feel free to update your original post with more information and I can provide you with a more specific answer.